# Error "identifier 'nombre_procedimiento' must be declared PL/SQL

Tags: mysql, oracle, stored-procedure, plsql

estoy intentando crear un procedimiento que me muestre el número total de empleados, la suma de los salarios y la suma de las comisiones de un departamento que es pasado por parámetro, pero me salta siempre el mismo error al ejecutar, me dice que el identidicador 'nombre_procedimiento' debe ser declarado...

El código es el siguiente:

```
create or replace procedure Pcalcularsueldosdep (
dep in department.department_id%type) is

cursor datos (dep department.department_id%type) is
  select count(*) as empleados, sum(salary) as salarios, nvl(sum(commission),0) as comisiones
  from employee
  where department_id = dep;

datos_dep datos%rowtype;

begin
open datos(dep);
fetch datos into datos_dep;
while (datos%found) loop
  dbms_output.put_line('Total empleados: ' || datos_dep.empleados ||
  'Suma de los salarios: ' || datos_dep.salarios ||
  'Suma de las comisiones: ' || datos_dep.comisiones);
  fetch datos into datos_dep;
end loop;

  close datos;
  end Pcalcularsueldosdep;
  /

execute Pcalculardueldosdep(30);
```

Y cuando ejecuto me salta el siguiente error:

```
Error que empieza en la línea 25 del comando:
execute Pcalculardueldosdep(30)
Informe de error:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'PCALCULARDUELDOSDEP' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

La verdad es que no termino de comprender del todo los modos (in, out, in out) de los parámetros, supongo que el error estará ahí, pero he probado poniendo el parámetro como out y declarándolo después y nada, mismo error, ya no sé qué hacer.

Cuando ejecute el procedimiento lo que quiero es que me saque el mensaje que tengo en el dbms_output.put_line.

Un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: El error es claro, revisa la última línea: execute Pcalculardueldosdep(30); Dice dueldos, no sueldos., por lo que no coincide con el nombre de tu procedimiento

Comment: Madre mía, llevo como una hora larga dándole vueltas y haciéndolo de veinte formas diferentes y no me había dado cuenta de eso... Creo que va siendo hora de descansar la mente, porque se ve que no estoy fino ya... Muchas gracias JYass. Yo pensaba que era algo de los modos de los parámetros, que no termino de verlos... Lo dicho, muchísimas gracias, y buenas noches!